# wrong result of query in vb6

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, jet

I am running a query which give me correct result from mdb and while I am running the same query with vb6 it returns one less record in the result.

Can someone tell me what is the exact problem?

my query is:

```
select * from kot where form = 34
```

Comment: You will have to provide some of that VB6 code in order for us to help you.

Comment: And maybe also provide details on the missing record.

Comment: Show the code where you loop through the record set returned.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful, but you can also check the `count` (number of rows) first:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM kot WHERE form = 34
```